# What "this is ClassName" statement mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm reading a C# project to implement a similar simple version of it in Python.

- *I'm not a C# programmer*

Somewhere in codes there is a `this` and `is` statement together that I can't figure out what they are doing together:

```
public abstract class PredictionTrial
{

...

   public bool DoneSuccessfully
   {
      get
      {
          return (this is PredictionTrialSuccess);
      }
   }

...

}
```

- `PredictionTrialSuccess` is a subclass of this class.

My question is that what `this is` is doing here with the combination of get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It means that the class is assignable from `PredictionTrialSuccess` type.

Take a look at [`is` keyword in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is).

A similar construction in python would be:

```
class A(object):
    def DoneSuccessfully(self):
        return isinstance(self, PredictionTrialSuccess)

class PredictionTrialSuccess(A):
    pass
```

Comment: I guess to make it same as C# example in question, we should put a `@property` decorators before defining `DoneSuccessfully`.

Answer (score 3):

If the dynamic type (the conrete type of your object at runtime) is `PredictionTrialSuccess` (or a subclass of it) then the property `DoneSuccessfully` will return `true`